# A Follow up question of **Confused by limit superior and limit inferior definition**

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

This is follow up question of [Confused by limit superior and limit inferior definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363080/confused-by-limit-superior-and-limit-inferior-definition)

> **Definition:**
>
> Suppose $\limsup x_n \in \mathbb R$. Then $\beta = \limsup x_n$ if and only if for all $\epsilon > 0$,
>
> **(i)**  $x_n < \beta + \epsilon$ for all except finitely many values of n
>
> **(ii)**  $x_n > \beta - \epsilon$ for infinitely many values of n

**My Understanding** I completly understand the  $x_n < \beta + \epsilon$ and
$x_n > \beta - \epsilon$ thing of the definition.
I take sequences$\left\{ S_{n}\right\} $ {bouded,for sake of simplicity}
on the real line .And two subsequences $\left\{ S_{n_{k}}\right\} $and
$\left\{ S_{n_{k'}}\right\} $,monotonically decreasing and increasing
respectiverly.It becomes obvious $\left\{ S_{n_{k}}\right\} \longrightarrow lower$
bound
and $\left\{ S_{n_{k'}}\right\} $$\longrightarrow$upper bound .Eventually
both sequences will fall in $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of lower bound
and upper bound.

> **Problem** What is meaning of **for all except finitely many values of n** and **for infinitely many values of n**

Comment: You quoted a *definition*. What is supposed to be defined in that definition?

Comment: Eventually it can *never* jump too far above the limsup, staying within epsilon. It can *always* jump arbitrarily far below the limsup but must always return to the epsilon neighborhood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For all except finitely many values of $n$*: Means that the set of natural numbers that do not satisfy the property is finite. For example, the set of all numbers $>100$.

*For infinitely many values of $n$*: Means that the set of natural numbers that satisfy the property is infinite. For example, all even numbers.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Very precise translation of such phrases like infinitely many. +1