# Learning Advice from Algebra to Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, reference-request

I've been working through D&F's *Abstract Algebra* for about 2 months now after already completing and singular honors course in algebra at school, and I find it to be a breath of fresh air. I love how extensive they are and the flow and workability of the problems.

However, my learning real analysis has been much more difficult for me. My school teaches with Carothers' *Real Analysis* and I've thoroughly read and reread baby Rudin's first two chapters. But I just can't get there. I get bogged down in really fine minutia and end up losing track of what I'm trying to learn. For example, I remember really struggling with Carothers' two characterizations of Limit Superior. Working through those exercises wore me out to the point of feeling defeated.

So here's my question: what can I do differently? Should I explore more texts? Should I continue to try to gain more mathematical maturity with a textbook I like and then attempt to revisit real analysis? Or should I just go in and force it?

Comment: **Always**...but really **always**, explore more texts. The basic definition of lim sup in Carothers is the one I learned and it is really abstract and hard to grasp at first. Continue to go on this...

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1893725/72031

Comment: Yes, thank you. I appreciate the link, but this post was not to vent frustration over limsup. It was only an example of something that took me longer than I think it should've to understand. My question is really about what other resources or strategies I should be using in further studies.

Answer (score 1):

As for algebra and analysis,  i was told repeatedly that people tend to be better at one than the other...  maybe you are more of an algebraist...  but, by all means try going further  (graduating ,say, to Rudin; doing more coursework;   checking out other real analysis texts etc...)...  I'm not sure you can't be good at both...

lim sup and lim inf *are* somewhat tricky and subtle notions...