# Alternative characterization of lim sup or lim inf. Proof explanation

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, limsup-and-liminf

This is a question about Theorem (2.18) in [Stromberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534980120).

> Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $a\in\mathbb{R}^\#$ (the $\#$ stands for the extended real numbers). Then (i) $a=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n$ if and only if whenever $\alpha<a$ we have $\lbrace n\in\mathbb{N}:x_n<\alpha\rbrace$ is finite and whenever $a<\beta$ we have $\lbrace n\in\mathbb{N}:x_n<\beta\rbrace$ is infinite;

There is a second part for the $\limsup$, but I'm not interested in it at the moment. My question is about the proof in the only if part. The author's proof goes as follows:

Conversely, suppose that $a$ satisfies both the "$\alpha$ condition" and the "$\beta$ condition" of (i). If $a=-\infty$, then $a\leq y.$

First question: I can see that if $a$ is infinity, $a\leq y$. How does this help to the proof? In other words, is this a proof that for this particular $a$, this is the $\limsup$?

If $a>-\infty$, then, given $\alpha < a$ we can choose $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha \leq x_n$ for all $n\geq k_0$.

Second question: The $\alpha$ condition says that if $\alpha <a$, then there are finitely many elements of the sequence $x_n$ that are less than $\alpha$. How can I be sure that there are infinitely many elements to the right of $\alpha$, why not use before hand the $\beta$ condition?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1893725/72031) which explains the properties in your question. I think your book uses the more popular definition $$\liminf x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\, \{x_k: k>n\}, \liminf x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf\, \{x_k:k>n\} $$

Comment: Regarding the last question at end note that the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ conditions are independent and one can't use one to prove another. Rather both need to proved / verified separately. Also "finite number of terms of the sequence are less than $\alpha$" implies "an infinite number of terms of the sequence are to the right of $\alpha$" but not conversely.

Comment: You are interested in "only if" part ie the definitions in my first comment imply the $\alpha, \beta$ conditions. It is best to apply the definition for three cases separately $a=-\infty, a=\infty, a\in\mathbb {R} $.

Comment: Ok, got it. What you mean is that if $a<\beta$ and there are infinitely many elements less than $\beta$, one can pick "the wrong" $\alpha'$ such that you don't have infinitely many to the right of $\alpha'$. Is this correct?

Comment: No i didn't mean that. You have to verify these conditions independently. They are not related to each other. Trying to view them that way will not help. If $\alpha<a<\beta$ then there are only a finite number of $x_n$ less than $\alpha$ and hence the remaining infinite number of $x_n$ lie to right of $a$. Further there are infinitely many $x_n$ less than $\beta $ and out of these only a finite number are less than $\alpha $. In conclusion interval $(\alpha, \beta) $ contains an infinite number of $x_n$ and a finite number lie to left of this interval. Cont'd..

Comment: However one can have an infinite number of $x_n$ also lying to the right of interval $(\alpha, \beta) $. In the special case when only a finite number of $x_n$ lie outside interval $(\alpha, \beta) $ the sequence converges to $a$.

Comment: You can also visualize in following manner. Let $a, b$ be $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of sequence $x_n$ and consider interval $J$ whose left endpoint is less than $a$ and right end point is greater than $b$. Then only a finite number of terms of sequence lie outside interval $J$.

Comment: Ok. Another quick question, if you agree. One can deduce that $y<\beta$ ($y$ is the supremum of the $y_k$'s). Why is not possible that $a<y$?. Suppose this is true, then I can find som e$a<y_k$. This would imply that there are infinitely many $x_n$, $n\geq k$ to the right of $a$. This is wrong, one has to have $a\geq y$, but I can't see why.

Comment: I think you need to formulate your query precisely. I have the information $a=\liminf x_n$ and $a<\beta$. What is $y$ and $y_k$?

Comment: $y_k = \inf \lbrace x_n : n\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq k\rbrace$, $y=\sup \lbrace  y_k : k \in\mathbb{N}\rbrace$.

Comment: I got that. And $y=\lim_{k\to\infty} y_k$ and since $y_k $ is increasing this is also supremum of $y_k$. You need to prove $a=y$. Suppose $a<y$ then by nature of supremum we have a $y_k$ such that $a<y_k\leq y$ and $y_k$ also satisfies beta condition so that there are infinitely many $x_n$ less than $y_k$ and this contradicts $x_n\geq y_k$ for $n\geq k$. Similarly let $y<a$ and derive a contradiction based on alpha condition.

Comment: Could you check this statement to prove the $\alpha$ condition? Actually I didn't use it. One can check that $\alpha \leq y$. Suppose $y<a$, then there is $\alpha_1\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $y<\alpha_1<a$. But we have said $\alpha\leq y$ for any $\alpha < a$. Thus $a\leq y$.

Comment: $\alpha $ is not a given number like $a$ or $y$ so you can't say $\alpha\leq y$.

Comment: Well, the complete argument to get $\alpha \leq y$ is this. Let $\alpha < a$, we can choose $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\alpha \leq x_n$ for all $n\geq k_0$. Thus $\alpha \leq y_{k_0}\leq y_k$ for $k\geq k_0$ and so $\alpha\leq \sup\lbrace y_k: k\in\mathbb{N}\rbrace=y $.

Comment: well then its fine. if for every $\alpha < a$ you have proved $\alpha \leq y$ then it implies $a\leq y$. And this completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for being involved, many would have dropped on first sight.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. I would suggest you to take your time and formulate a well written answer and post it here for benefit of others who are in a similar position position like you. Also take care in these difficult times.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Paramanad Singh, here is the full answer in case someone is interested in it. The question is about the only if part of the theorem, so I will stick to this part alone. I will rewrite the proof given in the book along with comments without edition about the discussion that happened in the comments.

> Conversely, suppose that $a$ satisfies both the "$\alpha$ condition" and the "$\beta$ condition". If $a = -\infty$, then  $$$a\leq y$. If $a>-\infty$, then, given $\alpha < a$, we can choose $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha \leq x_n$ for all $n\geq k_0$.

The $\alpha$ condition means that there are finite elements in the sequence $(x_n)$ smaller than $\alpha$. This implies that there are infinite $x_n$ such that $x_n>\alpha$.

> Thus $\alpha< y_{k_0}$ and so we obtain $$\alpha \leq \sup\lbrace y_k:k\in\mathbb{N} \rbrace=y.\quad (1) $$ Since (1) holds for all $\alpha< a$, we have, whether or not $a=-\infty$, that $$a\leq y.\quad (2) $$

Suppose $y<a$. We have seen that $\alpha \leq y$ so $\alpha \leq y < a$. Since reals are dense, there is an $\alpha_1$ such that $y<\alpha_1<a$. But we have proved $\alpha\leq y$ for every $\alpha<a$ so $y<a$ is a contradiction. Thus $a\leq y$.

> If $a=\infty$ the proof is complete. If $a<\infty$, let $a<\beta$. By the "$\beta$ condition" we see that $y_k < \beta$ for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and therefore $$y\leq \beta.\quad (3)$$ Since (3) holds for every $\beta > a$, we have $$y\leq a.\quad (4)$$

Suppose $\beta <y$. Since $y$ is the supremum, there is $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\beta < y_{k_0}$. But then since $y_{k_0} = \inf\lbrace x_n: n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq k_0 \rbrace$, there are infinite terms in the sequence such that $\beta < x_n$. But this is in contradiction with the "$\beta$ condition" and thus $y\leq \beta$.

> Finally combine (2) and (4) to get $a=y=\liminf x_n$.