# To prove a characterisation of $\limsup$ for bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

I want to show that $M = \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$, where $a_n$ is bounded, is *characterised by:*

> $\forall \epsilon > 0$, we have $a_n<M+\epsilon$ for all but finitely many $n$, and $M-\epsilon<a_n$ for infinitely many $n$.

I am starting off with $$M = \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (\sup\{a_k:k\ge n\}) \ne \pm\infty$$
which means that:

For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an integer $N > 1$ such that $M - \epsilon < \sup\{a_k : k \ge n\} < M + \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.

So $a_k < M+\epsilon$ for $k\ge n$, and the only possible exceptions to this might be $(a_k)_{i=1}^{n-1}$, which are finite in number. How do I show that $M-\epsilon<a_n$ for infinitely many $n$?

**Edit:**
**What would a corresponding characterization for $\liminf$ be?** I'm thinking $$m = \liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (\inf\{a_k:k\ge n\}) \ne \pm\infty$$ which means that:

For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an integer $N > 1$ such that $m - \epsilon < \inf\{a_k : k \ge n\} < m + \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.

may lead to

> $\forall \epsilon > 0$, we have $a_n>m-\epsilon$ for all but finitely many $n$, and $m+\epsilon>a_n$ for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: If this were true for only finitely many $n$, then take $n_{\epsilon}=\max n$ of these and you get $a_n\le M-\epsilon$ for $n>n_{\epsilon}$ this contradict that $M$ is limsup.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! Is my characterization for $\liminf$ correct?

Comment: The $M$ in the inf part should be $m$, but otherwise you should be good.

Comment: @macton Edited, thanks!

Comment: You may have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1893725/72031).

Comment: Thank you, very insightful!