# Difficulties in understanding this definition of a limit superior

Tags: definition, limsup-and-liminf

[image]

What is the symbol ε in this definition of a limit superior?

I tried to understand it through given statemets about limit superior such as in $(i)$ where if all members of the sequence satisfy $$x_n < L+ε,$$ then perhaps ε should be the difference between the supremum of this sequence and its limit superior.

But then according to $(ii)$ $$x_n > L-ε,$$ ε should also be the difference between this sequence's limit superior and its infimum?

Which perhaps is not contradicting the statement in $(i)$ but to me it sounds as if it does for some reason.

It would be of great help if someone could define this ε.

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: It's not a specific $\epsilon$, it's all positive numbers. The definition is saying that anything greater than the limit superior is an eventual upper bound for the sequence and anything less than the limit superior is not. The limit superior is what the supremum of the sequence is as it approaches infinity.

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1893725/72031

Comment: @JohnDouma So  just serves to say that anything above limit sup will have finitely many terms less than it, and anything less than limit sup will have infinitely many terms greater than it?

Comment: Yes. Compare it to the definition of the supremum. If $u$ is a least upper bound then anything above it is an upper bound and anything below it is not. Therefore, if $u$ is the least upper bound of a set $X$, for all $\epsilon\gt 0$ and $x\in X$, $x\lt u+\epsilon$ and there exists $x\in X$ such that $x\gt u-\epsilon$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Tank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think an example will serve to clarify:

Take the sequence to be $\{x_n=\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$

The limsup of the sequence is 0.

why?

$(\forall \epsilon>0)$ only a finite number of terms satisfies $x_n>0+\epsilon=\epsilon\implies x_n>\epsilon$.

namely, $n<\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

This is condition i. of the definition.

Also an infinite number of terms satisfies:

$x_n>-\epsilon$.

Infact all terms are non-negative.

This is condition ii. of the definition.